# php glob pattern ending may or may not have

Tags: php

I am trying to find files that start with "image_1" and may or may not end with "_main"

```
$glob=glob("/image_1{_main}.jpeg");
```

So it would match

image_1_main

image_1

but not image_11. What would be the pattern here? Do I use {_main}?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/

Comment: I took a look at that, and it says use something like {gif,jpg,png} to match ending. So "image_1{_main}" but how do I make "{_main}" optional. I can't use "image_1*" or I will match "image_11" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add the flag to globe to make "{}" work. You need "GLOB_BRACE" in glob function;

```
$glob=glob("/image_1{,_main}.jpeg",GLOB_BRACE);
```